# Cannot find symbol class BaseAdapter

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting this error when running an android project just converted from ADT(Eclipse).

Found a thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/lWpyVCcyzIw) but no answer. Any one has any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by moving that Adapter class(extending from BaseAdapter) to another java file.

Answer (score 3):

This is workaround.

`class XXXAdapter extends android.widget.BaseAdapter {
}`

Use `android.widget.BaseAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter`

Comment: Some extra information with this answer would improve it